# Rotating a polygon around its center in c++

Tags: c++, image-rotation

I would like to rotating a polygon around its center in C++.

I want a rotating polygon around its center, not a result of the rotation.

But result is rotated polygon.

My code is following :

```
double pi = atan(1) * 4;
double radian = 180 / pi;
int N = 1;
double angle = radian * (N % 10);
double Sin = sin(angle);
double Cos = cos(angle);

int Radius = 60;
int xC = 256;
int yC = 256;

for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    for (int k = 0; k < 10; k++) {
        Draw1Dot(256+i, 256+k, 0.2f, 0.7f, 0.7f);
    }
}

time_t start, end;
DrawCircle(Radius, xC, yC, Sin, Cos);

do {

    time(&start);
    end = start;

    while (end - start != 3) {
        void clear();
        N++;
        time(&end);
        DrawCircle(Radius, xC, yC, Sin, Cos);
    }
} while (N == 10);
```

**My goal is that as N increases, the circle rotated about its center.**

I used the Sleep() function for a smooth moving effect.

-edit-

I was listened from someone that want to see DrawCircle() function..

That function is just drawing circle, so I don't write that.

Drawing Code is following :

```
int Check = 1 - Radius;
int x = 0;
int y = Radius;

//circle edge drawing code
Draw1Dot(xC + x + (Radius * Cos), yC + y + (Radius * Sin), 1.f, 1.f, 1.f);      //1
Draw1Dot(yC + y + (Radius * Cos), xC + x + (Radius * Sin), 1.f, 1.f, 1.f);      //2
Draw1Dot(yC + y + (Radius * Cos), xC - x + (Radius * Sin), 1.f, 1.f, 1.f);      //3
Draw1Dot(xC + x + (Radius * Cos), yC - y + (Radius * Sin), 1.f, 1.f, 1.f);      //4
Draw1Dot(xC - x + (Radius * Cos), yC - y + (Radius * Sin), 1.f, 1.f, 1.f);      //5
Draw1Dot(yC - y + (Radius * Cos), xC - x + (Radius * Sin), 1.f, 1.f, 1.f);      //6
Draw1Dot(yC - y + (Radius * Cos), xC + x + (Radius * Sin), 1.f, 1.f, 1.f);      //7
Draw1Dot(xC - x + (Radius * Cos), yC + y + (Radius * Sin), 1.f, 1.f, 1.f);      //8

while (x <= y) {
    x++;
    if (Check < 0)
        Check += (2 * x) + 1;
    else {
        Check += 2 * (x - y) + 1;
        y--;
    }
    Draw1Dot(xC + x + (Radius * Cos), yC + y + (Radius * Sin), 1.f, 1.f, 1.f);      //1
    Draw1Dot(yC + y + (Radius * Cos), xC + x + (Radius * Sin), 1.f, 1.f, 1.f);      //2
    Draw1Dot(yC + y + (Radius * Cos), xC - x + (Radius * Sin), 1.f, 1.f, 1.f);      //3
    Draw1Dot(xC + x + (Radius * Cos), yC - y + (Radius * Sin), 1.f, 1.f, 1.f);      //4
    Draw1Dot(xC - x + (Radius * Cos), yC - y + (Radius * Sin), 1.f, 1.f, 1.f);      //5
    Draw1Dot(yC - y + (Radius * Cos), xC - x + (Radius * Sin), 1.f, 1.f, 1.f);      //6
    Draw1Dot(yC - y + (Radius * Cos), xC + x + (Radius * Sin), 1.f, 1.f, 1.f);      //7
    Draw1Dot(xC - x + (Radius * Cos), yC + y + (Radius * Sin), 1.f, 1.f, 1.f);      //8
}

//Circle filling code
for (int y = -Radius; y <= Radius; y++) {
    for (int x = -Radius; x <= Radius; x++) {
        if (x*x + y*y <= Radius*Radius)
            Draw1Dot(xC + x + Radius*Cos, yC + y + Radius*Sin, 1.f, 1.f, 1.f);
    }
}
```

Comment: Where is `DrawCircle()` defined? Please upload the complete code so that we can try it ourselves.

Comment: @AnmolSinghJaggi edit complet :)

Comment: Are you rotating a circle? You don't draw any polygons

Comment: rotating circle around its center..hmm, what do you expect to see? :)

Comment: Where is `Draw1Dot()` defined?

Comment: @harold Polygon or circle isn't important. focusing on 'ROTATING SOMETHING'

Comment: @OlegBogdanov I want a circle that moves like a moon rotating around the earth.

Comment: @AnmolSinghJaggi Draw1Dot() function is similar putpixel() function.

Comment: What is `putpixel()`? In what library is it defined?

Answer (score 0):

You aren't changing the angle by which you draw your shape.

```
int Radius = 60;
int xC = 256;
int yC = 256;
double angle = START_ANGLE;

time_t start, end;
time(&start);

while (angle < MAX_ANGLE) {
    clear();
    time(&end);
    angle = ANGULAR_SPEED * (end - start);
    DrawCircle(Radius, xC, yC, sin(angle), cos(angle));    
}
```

You will need to define some values for START_ANGLE, MAX_ANGLE and ANGULAR_SPEED

Comment: I take your answer, but output is same as before..

I want a moving output like a video, but it stops like a picture.